# how to initialize sockets in linux environemnt

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I have a code snippet to initialize a sockets in windows. How would I initialize the socket in Linux environment.

```
    WSADATA wsa
    if(WAStartup(MkeWORD(2,2), $wsa) !=0 )
    {
    exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: I advise to give a look at this material: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#structs

Comment: **WHY** do sockets even need to be initialized?

Comment: Your code has several typos. Don't retype code here; copy and paste the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you don't initialize a network environment like WSA. Sockets can be used out of the box.
See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html for documentation.

Comment: Not just Linux, but all non-Windows platforms. Windows is the ONLY platform where you have to initialize the socket library before you can use it.